# SQL Producing an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the following SQL syntax on a classic ASP page. `HostLatitude` is unfortunately a `nvarchar(20)`, hence the decimal conversion.

```
SELECT 
    HostID, HostLatitude, HostLongitude, HostNames, HostPropertyName, 
    HostStreet, HostSuburb, HostCity, HostPhone, HostMobile, 
    HostLastUpdated, HostJoinDate, HostPostCode, hgbCounter, HostStateID 
FROM 
    Hosts
WHERE 
    HostLatitude IS NOT NULL
    AND Datalength(HostLatitude) > 5
    AND CONVERT(decimal, HostLatitude) > 51
    AND CONVERT(decimal, HostLatitude) < 53
    AND HostRegionID = 303
    AND HostLastUpdated >CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-02-21 00:00:00', 102) - 730 
    AND Datalength(HostLatitude) > 2 
    AND Datalength(HostLongitude) > 1 
    AND HostApproved = 1 
    AND HostDisabled = 0 
    AND AdminDisabled = 0 
ORDER BY 
    HostID DESC;
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

If I comment out the following the query runs:

```
AND CONVERT(decimal, HostLatitude) > 51
AND CONVERT(decimal, HostLatitude) < 53
```

Comment: what is value in HostLatitude? I think there are some value cannot convert to decimal, please check value of HostLatitude in your table.

Comment: Do you think, maybe, it might be related to the *content* of this column, and so it might be worth showing us some sample values?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you think, maybe, if he realized that he wouldn't have needed to ask this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

This means that somewhere along the line HostLatitude is populated with some non-numeric characters.  You could use a CASE clause to check for ISNUMERIC() and return null or some other default value when it's not a number

```
AND case when isnumeric(HostLatitude) = 1 
           then convert(decimal, HostLatitude)
           else null 
    end) > 51
```

Comment: Be careful when using the `IsNumeric` function before converting to `decimal`.  `IsNumeric` does not always as expected and it not a 100% safe filter for converting to decimal.  See here: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2011/01/13/98746.aspx

Comment: @PhilipFourie +1 Good point.  Hopefully he can take the approach of just cleaning up HostLatitude and validating what values go in there in the future if that's an option.  But if not, he could always just test for the edge cases... it shouldn't be too hard to identify what they are.  And possibly put that logic in a sql function.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `HostLatitude` contains a string value that cannot be converted to decimal.
For example:

- 'abc'
- ''
- 123,45

Comment: Looks like there is junk in the table. I just need to find out a way to search for records with any non numeric characters + the decimal symbol. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Craig Ray: please consider up-voting the answer if it helped with your problem and accept it if it led you to the solution.